# Apache Geode scaling

Tags: nosql, geode

I'm trying to measure the performance of Geode
I have 3 identical hosts to test it.
I created a partitioned region.

1. I started a geode cluster with one server.
   I do "get" and "put" operations in the loop.
   I get about 50000 op/sec.
2. Add started a cluster with three geode nodes.
   I do get and put operations in the loop.
   I get the same 50000 op/sec.

I would expect to see the increased performance, but it is suprisingly the same for 1-node cluster and 3-nodes cluster.

Could you please help. What are the possible settings to change in order to get horizontal scalability.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you just got horizontal scalability for data storage at no loss of throughput :)

To horizontally scale your throughput, I think your workload was not enough to max-out the server. You need to start multiple clients (OR threads in a single client) against a single server until you do not see throughput increase by adding any new clients. At this point you start a new server. This new server should allow you to add more clients and horizontally scale your throughput.

You may find the [ycsb benchmark](https://github.com/brianfrankcooper/YCSB) useful, which allows you to start multiple threads in a client to perform operations.

Answer (score 0):

You should setuo and environment who you see a performance decrease with single node and then make same test with partitioned one.